# Google App MX records

Tags: forms, dns, cpanel, google-apps

So I have this very weird problem, I've been trying to fix it but it's just not working. I have a Google Apps account that I want to integrate google mail with my Emails. So I updated the MX records on the DNS settings of my domain to the following:

```
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM  1
ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 5
ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 5
ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 10
ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 10
```

With this configuration, All the emails that I send to my email address directly are sent to the Google apps without any problem and I can also reply easily from my google account, The problem arises when the form on my website sends email to my email address, I have checked the WP Logs the Form Submission emails gets sent through and it even goes to the Webmail inbox of the cPanel but none of the submissions from the Form get to the Google Apps inbox.

Additional Info:

I am using WP with Ninja Forms
I am using Godaddy Shared Hosting 
I have tested WP Logs to confirm that the emails are sent through from WP
I have also checked cPanel Webmail and all the form submissions are coming to this inbox.
I added the MX records by going to the DNS Management section of GoDaddy

The problem is none of the form submission emails are sent to the Google Apps Folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your 'From Email' in the form settings is entered correctly and that it is also different to the 'Admin Email'.
Providers can block emails if the 'From Email' is not entered, or entered the same as the recipient email address(Admin Email).
I believe Googles systems are among those which block messages sent in this way.